# Multiple zip codes separated by a comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to filter multiple zip codes in an input, there should be at least 2 zip SEPARATED by a COMA, I am trying to  validate them in javascript with the following code but it's now filtering, the submit send the form to the next page without error, anyone can help?

```
<script>
function validateMULTIZIP() {
    if(!/\d{11,}/.test(document.zipad.textfield.value) && document.getElementById('single').checked==false))
    {
         alert( "There should be a least two Zip codes separated by a coma." );
         document.zipad.textfield.focus() ;
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

This will check for two 5-digit numbers separated by a comma

```
^\d{5},\d{5}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

But, you said *at least* two, so that means it needs to be a little more flexible to accommodate more. If the user enters `12345,12345,12345` it needs to be valid.

```
^\d{5}(?:,\d{5})+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

What if the user adds a space after the comma? Such as `12345, 12345`. This is perfectly valid, so let's make sure our validator allows that.

```
^\d{5}(?:,\s*\d{5})+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Oh, and zip codes can have an optional `-1234` ending on them, too (known as [ZIP+4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code#ZIP.2B4). Maybe you want something like this

```
^\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?(?:,\s*\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Now strings like this would be valid

- 12345
- 12345, 12345,12345
- 12345, 12345-9999, 12345

---

**As a bonus**, let's say `12345, 12345` is invalid because it has the same zip code twice. Here's how we'd fix that

```
(?:(\d{5}),?)(?!.*\1)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

And here's the ZIP+4 version

```
(?:(\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?),?)(?!.*\1(?!-))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This one has a little added complexity because of possibility of (e.g.,) `12345, 12345-9999`. This is valid but because `12345` can appear more than once, it makes sure that a 5-digit zip code can't be invalidated by a unique 9-digit zip code.

**Note** these duplicate-checking regexps do not enforce the minimum of two unique zip codes. If you want to check for duplicates you'd need to combine the two.

```
var valid5DigitZipCodes = function(str) {
  if (! /^\d{5}(?:,\s*\d{5})+$/.test(str)) {
    alert("You need at least 2 zip codes");
    return false;
  }

  else if (! /(?:(\d{5}),?)(?!.*\1)/.test(str)) {
    alert("You entered a duplicate zip code");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};
```

And here's the ZIP+4 variant if you want to support that

```
var valid9DigitZipCodes = function(str) {
  if (! /^\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?(?:,\s*\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)+$/.test(str)) {
    alert("You need at least 2 zip codes");
    return false;
  }

  else if (! /(?:(\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?),?)(?!.*\1(?!-)).test(str) {
    alert("You entered a duplicate zip code");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};
```

Comment: nice diagrams, are you using an application to auto generate these?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming (from your code) that ZIP code contains five digits and no other characters, you could use:

```
/\d{5},\d{5}/.test(document.zipad.textfield.value)
```

You regex: `\d{11,}` means "any digit, eleven times or more", that's why it's broken.

Comment: Thanks! work just fine, I appreciate that, keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution without using regex would be splitting zip Codes by comma then check for the size of the resulting array.

Sample code:

```
<input type="text" id="in"></input>
<button onclick="validate()">Click</button>
```

JS

```
function validate() {
    var inp = document.getElementById("in");
    var content = inp.value;
    var correct = validateZipString(content);
    if (correct) {
        alert("ok");
    } else {
        alert("not ok");
    }
}

function validateZipString(zipString) {
    var zipCodes = zipString.split(',');
    if (zipCodes.length < 2) return false;
    for (var i = 0; i < zipCodes.length; i++) {
        //validate each zipCode if required
    }
    return true;
}
```

here is a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VcNd9/3/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else interested in the variant that also matches 1 zip or more rather than two or more. Simply change the + quantifier for * at the end of the expression.

From:

```
^\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?(?:,\s*\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)+$
```

To:

```
^\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?(?:,\s*\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)*$
```

For example:

`<input type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="^\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?(?:,\s*\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)*$">`